# Replace text from a MySQL dump using cat (or something else) in shell

Tags: unix, shell

I've got a database dump in MySQL where I want to replace ocurrencies of paths that are in the dump as plaintext.

In this particular case I'd like to replace:

```
/var/www/
```

for

```
/home/www/
```

How could I safely do that using cat or any other shell tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat old.file | sed 's%/var/www/%/home/www/%g' > new.file
```

Comment: The cat can be "optimized away", of course. However, I prefer to leave it as it is for two reasons. 1) This solution also works when the dump comes from standard output of a process instead of a file. 2) It clearly shows that old.file is only read, but not written.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sed 's/\/var\/www\//\/home\/www\//' old_file > new_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub("/var/www/","/home/www/")}1' mydump >temp && mv temp mydump
```